# How to access i18n-express dictionary in router?

Tags: node.js, express, dictionary, internationalization

I am using express and i18n-express for internationalization. It works perfectly in JADE templates, but I am not able to access dictionary in routers (i.e. I need to send some text as result for Ajax request). I expect, it is very simple and I am just missing it (and I am not able to google it :-( ).

The initialization of i18n-express:
    var i18n=require("i18n-express");

```
/* Localization */
app.use(i18n({
  translationsPath: path.join(__dirname, 'lang'),
  siteLangs: ["en","cs"]
}));
```

Now I need to access specific localized text in router. I.e.:

```
app.get('/getLocalizedText', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(LOCALIZED_TEXT);
});
```

Does anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 2):

The `req.i18n_texts` object has all the values you need.Checkout the [source](https://github.com/koalazak/i18n-express/blob/master/index.js#L150) if you want to know more.

```
app.get('/getLocalizedText', function(req, res, next) {
  // to get the value of HELLO_MESSAGE
  res.send(req.i18n_texts.HELLO_MESSAGE);
});
```